# jquery ui dialog won't open when assigning the ID through innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-dialog, innerhtml

I ran into a small problem. here is a sample what im doing.

```
 htmlValue += '<a href="#" id="shareOpen" style="margin: 0 2px 0 2px; float: left;" 
title="Share File" class="version ui-icon ui-icon-heart"></a>';
 $(modalDivObj).html(htmlValue);
```

I am writing this on a loop on a page with a bunch of other functions. and everything is writing fine and appears. However, when I click on `#shareOpen` the dialog won't open. I tried just hard coding the same html and it works fine. The problem is when I do it through `.html()` it won't write the ID? I don't know.

here is some of the on page html and jquery.

```
$("#shareFile").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: "true",
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        buttons: {
            "Done": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#shareOpen").click(function () {
        $("#shareFile").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
 <div id="shareFile"  runat ="server">



 </div>
```

Comment: When are you calling the various pieces of Javascript? You have to make sure you've created the 'shareOpen' element before you try and bind the click element.

Comment: Im getting the shareFile by the ID and just adding html through javascript. but when i put that line it shows the icon but the ID is messed up.

Comment: What is the modalDivObj?

Comment: var modalDivObj = document.getElementById('files-icons');

Comment: its the div im writing the info from the database. it writes everything fine... but the "button" or the icon that im clicking to bring up the dialog won't pop up.

Comment: What do you mean by the ID being messed up? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said I think the most likely issue is that the click event is not being bound correctly.

Try using the following instead of your current call to click:

```
$("#files-icons").on("click", "#shareOpen", function () {
    $("#shareFile").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

This will bind the event handler to any elements with ID 'shareOpen' that are children of #files-icons, regardless of when they are added to the page.

I believe the problem is that you are binding a click handler on an element that doesn't yet exists in the page.

Comment: Actually, if you are only creating "#shareOpen" once then it might be a better move to use your originally click binding but move it so it gets called after you set the HTML content of modalDivObj.